# how to close parent div with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and when click on close icon, the div `echomessage` in which the close icon, should disappear , but all divs with class `echomessage` disappear now.
So it should close only the div in which close button is part of

```
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn"><i class="fas fa-times echoclose"></i></span>  
   <?php echo 'Upload successful: <b>'.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'</b>'; ?>
</div>

$('.closebtn').click(function(){
        $(".echomessage").fadeOut(300);
    });
```

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you told it to. You wrote that every element that has the class "echomessage" should "fadeOut". Can you rephrase the question maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Find the div with `echomessage` in the close button's parent element.

```
$(this).parent('.echomessage').fadeOut(300)
```

Comment: @JackMaessen Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solved your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Access the parent with the class `.echomessage` retrieving the current one through `$(this)`:

```js
$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  $(this).parent(".echomessage").fadeOut(300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a **pure JavaScript approach**, you can use the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to retrieve all the `closebtn` elements, follow up by the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to retrieve and add a `click` listener to each `closebtn` element and finally the [parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) property to either remove or hide the parent element of the child `closebtn` element.

You can check out the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of what I described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

document.querySelectorAll(".closebtn").forEach(btn => {
 btn.addEventListener("click", function(){this.parentElement.style.display ="none"})
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
   <p>PHP CODE HERE</p>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
   <p>PHP CODE HERE</p>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success echomessage" role="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">X</span>  
   <p>PHP CODE HERE</p>
</div>
```